# Flutter: Stack - Offstage - TextFormField - issue with focus

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack of a list of Offstage Widgets.
Each of these Offstage widgets refers to a MaterialApp to display a Form.
Each of these forms contains several TextFormFields.

The issue I have is that the first and second Offstage items TextFormFields never get the focus (of course considering a correct offstage: index).

In order to make it work, if I put the first Offstage to the third position (thus on top), everything is working fine.

This most probably comes from the notion of Stack or from the Offstage.

Is there a way to force the equivalent of a "*z-index*"?
I also tried to use the IndexedStack but the result is identical.

Should I use something else but the Offstage?

Many thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xF4FFFFFF),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              canvasColor: Colors.amber[700],
              primaryColor: Colors.white,
              textTheme: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800])),
            ),
        child: new BottomNavigationBar(
            iconSize: 8.0,
            currentIndex: index,
            onTap: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                this.index = index;
              });
            },
             type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: new Text('Sign In',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                  icon: new Container(height: 8.0),
                ),
                new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: new Text('Register',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                  icon: new Text('No account yet',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0)),
                ),
                new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  title: new Text('lost password',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
                  icon: new Container(height: 8.0),
                ),
              ]),
      ),
      body: new SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
          new Offstage(
              offstage: index != 0,
              child: new MaterialApp(
                home: new LoginForm(),
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              )),
          new Offstage(
            offstage: index != 1,
            child: new MaterialApp(
              home: new RegisterForm(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            ),
          ),
          new Offstage(
            offstage: index != 2,
            child: new MaterialApp(
              home: new LostPasswordForm(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing this instead of using `Navigator` or a `PageView`/`TabView` ?

Comment: Or even just a switch or if/else - if you don't need any animation between the pages you could build only the form you want to show...

Comment: Even if you both are right, the main objective of the question was to see if there is any reason that prevents a TextFormField from getting the focus in the circumstances explained in the question, while other Widgets such as RaisedButton are working...

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this question while trying to find the solution to a similar problem. You've probably moved on, but I'm pretty sure that this is the same issue described in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17098. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.